# C# LinkButton.PostBackUrl - New window without JS

Tags: c#, asp.net, linkbutton, postbackurl

Is it possible to use `asp:LinkButton` without JavaScript to open new windows?
Currently i have workable next code, but with JS.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkPcName" runat="server" OnClientClick="window.document.forms[0].target='_blank';" PostBackUrl='<%# Eval("ComputerId", "ComputerInfo.aspx?ComputerId={0}") %>'><%# Eval("pcName") %></asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: I use UpdatePanel and after a new window is opened from the parent window - JS error appearing like : "Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed. Common causes for this error are when the response is modified by calls to Response.Write(), response filters, HttpModules, or server trace is enabled."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As i know **linkbuttons** were originally designed to do a postback to the same page

If i were you i would use a **hyperlink** control instead

Comment: Yeah! Thanks guru! :P
I replaced it with
<asp:HyperLink ID="lnkPcName" runat="server" Target="_blank" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("ComputerId", "ComputerInfo.aspx?ComputerId={0}") %>'><%# Eval("pcName") %></asp:HyperLink>
And no more JavaScript error!!!!

Comment: I want to emulate the OnClick in my LinkButton through HyperLink. How can I achieve that? Thanks.